# How to split a variable with a space in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, split

his line works to split ","

```
$lastName, $firstName = $name -Split(",");
```

But I also want to split by SPACE.
I tried somenthing like this:

```
if ($name -match ",") {
    # $lastName, $firstName = $name -split(",");
    {
        else $lastName, $firstName = $name -split(" ");
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Your `if` isn't closing ther is a `{` instead of `}` and the code of the else needs to be in `{}` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine when written correctly:

```
if ($name -match ",") {
    # $lastName, $firstName = $name -split(",");
}
else {
    $lastName, $firstName = $name -split(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As the `-split` operator uses *regular expressions* you can just list the separators inside square brackets:

```
"foo,bar baz" -split "[, ]"
```

Comment: $lastName,$firstName = $name -Split("[, ]");

Answer (score 1):

As you might have both a space and a comma in between and in some languages (as with [Dutch Names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_name)) it is common to have tussenvoegsels, [prepositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition) or [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)) (e.g. [`Maarten van der Weijden`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maarten_van_der_Weijden)), I would take @Janne's (+1) answer one step further by adding a `+`(*one or more occurrences of the preceding element*) to the [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and `, 2` to the [`-Split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6), e.g.:

```
$LastName, $FirstName = "Weijden, Maarten van der" -Split '[, ]+', 2
```

Comment: What about [double-barreled surnames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name) being split at the first space instead of the comma? (+1 for the `,<Max-substrings>`)